# How do I use sscanf to split a string on a delimiter?

Tags: c++, scanf

I want to get only `7b` from `7b-7a` with `sscanf`

I tried:

```
char str[32] = "7b-7a";
char out[32];
sscanf(str, "%s-%s", out);
std::cout << out;
```

Output is: `7b-7a`

I need to output only `7b`

Comment: If you change `"%s-%s"` to `"%2s"`, then your code will work. This will limit the number of matched characters to 2 characters. If you want it to match everything up to the next `-`, then you should use `"%31[^-]"` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, the easier way would be to use streams and getline, like this.

https://godbolt.org/z/4TTKz5KPx

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>

int main(){
    std::string in{"7b-7a"};
    std::stringstream ss{in};

    std::string out;
    std::getline(ss, out, '-');
    std::cout << out << "\n";

}
```

Comment: You should use `std::istringstream` (ussed for input only) instead of `std::stringstream` (used for input/output).

Answer (score 2):

You can try sscanf like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str[32] = "7b-7a";
    char out[32];
    sscanf(str, "%[a-z0-9]-%*s",out);
    std::cout << out;
    return 0;
}
```